# SQL Alchemy performance if used only for raw sql?

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I intend to use very simple raw SQL in a Django project.
example:

`SELECT name,doc_id,doc_content,creation_date from doc_table where uid = 'xxx' limit 1 ;`

Primary requirements:

- Ease of doing SQL queries and getting data - eg. If I use MySQLdb , I do not want to repetitively do queries through cursor, then process the tuples to get a dictionary of required data.
- Protection against SQL injection , and proper escaping of data.

There are two choices,

a) Using SQLAlchemy , even if used only for raw SQL.

b) Use a wrapper written over MySQLdb, or write one.

I am inclined towards SQLAlchemy as I have read a lot of good things about it.

Will there be any significant performance overhead of using SQLAlchemy eg CPU usage,Memory usage as compared to a simpler MySQLdb wrapper , if I intend to use it only for simple raw SQL. All other batteries of SQLAlchemy are not of much use.

Comment: FYI, you can get dicts back from MySQLdb directly without processing tuples.  Just add: `import MySQLdb.cursors` and in your connect call add a named param `cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor`.  The iterator returned from `fetchall()` will be dictionaries.

Comment: So the assumption here is that the query is against a db for which you don't have a model?

Comment: @sberry Yes,I have seen that,I would want a wrapper over that to ease inserts ,updates ,selects.

Comment: *Why* don't you have a model? If it's an existing table, why not use `inspectdb` to create a model from the database?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Correction. I do have model, but not ORM . The models return dictionaries of data required which can be processed in view.

Comment: What? What does "I do have model but not ORM" mean? Either you have a Django model, or you don't. And if you don't, why not?

Comment: Please see the answer to [Why is SQLAlchemy insert with `sqlite` 25 times slower than using sqlite3 directly?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11769768/99594).  

Although it is not `mysql`, [Mike](http://stackoverflow.com/users/34549/zzzeek) posted a sample code for performance testing, which you can apply to your case with mySQL and extend to include all `CRUD` operation. 
  
From the results posted there, I would conclude that there should not be any significant performance degradation when using only [`SQLAlchemy Core`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/tutorial.html).

Comment: Also look at another SO answer to [Is SQLAlchemy still recommanded if only used for raw sql query?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11543303/99594).

Comment: @van Thanks for the input. It is helpful. Do you know any good lightweight wrapper written over MySQLdb ?

Comment: Nope, do not work with MySQL. Sorry.

Comment: @Van you can post your comment inputs as answers, I would be happy to accept it as correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*as requested, posting comments as an answer:*

Please see the answer to [Why is SQLAlchemy insert with sqlite 25 times slower than using sqlite3 directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11769768/99594). Although it is not `mysql`, Mike posted a sample code for performance testing, which you can apply to your case with mySQL and extend to include all CRUD operation. From the results posted there, I would conclude that there should not be any significant performance degradation when using only [SQLAlchemy Core](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/tutorial.html).

Also look at another SO answer to [Is SQLAlchemy still recommanded if only used for raw sql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543303/99594)